# Copying elements of an array in C having unexpected results

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I am trying to copy elements of an array using a simple copy function outside of main.
My code is as follows:

```
int* copy(int* nums){
    int size = sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]); // len of array
    int *arr = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int)); // dynamic allocation of array mem
    *arr = *nums; // copy operation
    return arr; // return copied arr
}

int main(){
    int nums[] = {1,2}; 
    int array[2];
    *array = *copy(nums); // operation in question
    printf("[%d, %d]", array[0], array[1]);
}
```

My output:

```
[1, 0]
```

It seems like the copy function is returning only the first element in my array. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: `sizeof()` is not used to determine the length of pointer array, it is only used to stack arrays eg, `int arr[3];`. So, add a parameter for length of the array. Also use `for loop` or `memcpy` for copying the data

Answer (score 0):

1. `*nums` returns the first element of `nums`
2. `*arr = whatever;` assigns `whatever` to the first element of `arr`

Thus, `*arr = *nums;` is a "copy *one element* operation". Same thing with `*array = *copy(nums);`, by the way.

Comment: `array[0]` = `*(array + 0)` = `*(array)` = `*array`
So `*arr = *nums`; is the same as `arr[0] = nums[0];`.

Comment: Thanks for that, made things clear as to what's happening. So, is there an efficient/easier way of copying elements over to another array without manually dereferencing the values I want copy? Thanks for humoring my newbie question.

Comment: @GianniCrivello, 1) `sizeof(nums) == sizeof(int *) == 8` (or maybe 4) since `nums` is a pointer, so you aren't actually calculating the size of the array; 2) If you had the correct size, you could've looped over each element and copied the values in the loop; 3) you can also copy multiple values at a time, which should be faster; 4) or simply use `memcpy`.